# WW2 German or Polish naval uniform?

Tags: navy, german

The photo attached shows a naval person from WW2 having his hair cut. I am trying to work out whether this is German or Polish Navy. Both looking at Google images are very similar with the 3 white bars around the collar. I am favouring Polish as the kerchief seems more like the Polish than the German. Can anyone give me a definitive assessment? [image: haircut]